# Released app crashes several hours after install

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am installing the application on my phone via Xcode in release mode. It works for a while without any problems. Then, for example, I try to open the application after a few hours, but it crashes immediately. What is the reason?

You can see here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hxwZ.jpg

Answer (score 0):

this usually happens when your app is no longer signed. Have you tried checking to see if your provision profile and certificate is still active. Might be worth revoking all certs and getting Xcode to remake it

Edit: also check settings> General > Profiles to see if it’s trusted (if using a free account which I don’t think you are since it’s release)

Comment: I use free account. The provision profile and certificate are still active. Could it be because I am using the free account?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this issue is related to Provisioning profile, You must check if on opening app you are working with some database values or APIs which might not working for particular case